# findelement is not throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, java-7

I want to write a test to check if a webelement with a specified text is not present on a page. This is the code for the method doing the job:

```
    public boolean checkOfAanvraagIsOpgevoerd (String titel)
{

    String quote = "\"";
    String titelMetQuotes = quote + titel +quote;
    titelMetQuotes = "dierdieboeboe";
    boolean isOpgevoerd=false;
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='listRequests']//h4/a[contains(text(),"+titelMetQuotes+")]"));
        isOpgevoerd=true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException NE) {
        NE.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isOpgevoerd;
}
```

Although I'm absolutely sure that there is no a tag on the page wich contains the text "dierdieboeboe" still the catch block is skipped. When I replace for instance h4 in h5 in the xpath expression the NoSuchElementException is thrown as expected. It seems that the contains part in the expression is ignored.

Comment: It could be that the tag is hidden. Do you get any result when the XPath is executed manually in the console of your browser? `$x(".//*[@id='listRequests']//h4/a[contains(text(),'dierdieboeboe')]")`

Comment: When entering this expression in Firepath the result is "no matching nodes"

Comment: If you don't get any result manually, then it's a timing issue. The element found by selenium is probably deleted after an asynchronous update/action. Try to add a delay to check if it's the case. If it is, add a waiter to synchronize your test.

Comment: I missed that you are removing the quoting when `titelMetQuotes` is assigned the second time with `dierdieboeboe`. Note that an XPath supports both single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (note the single quotes around the actual text):

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='listRequests']//h4/a[contains(text(),'"+titelMetQuotes+"')]")
```

[contains](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp) is a function that takes two strings. Hence the text of your variable `titelMetQuotes` needs to be quoted. Obviously, in this case it is easier to use single quotes.

Additionally, the variable name (titel with quotes) is quite misleading because it actually has no quotes for another flaw in the code:

```
String titelMetQuotes = quote + titel +quote;
titelMetQuotes = "dierdieboeboe";
```

The second line simply overwrites the quoted title with a non quoted string.

Finally, you don't need the leading dot in your xpath expression in order to locate the first element of any kind with id `listRequests`

Comment: Thanks this works. It works when the element with a certain text is not present as wel as when the element with a certain text is present. You made my day Würgspaß. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @Frank Nice to hear. I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: thnx for the extra tip about the leading dot. The codeline with "dierdieboeboe" was added for debugging reasons and I missed that the quotes were overwritten. Still wondering what was found by the expression without Quotes.